# Coloured output with git in cmd

Tags: git, windows-xp, cmd

Is there a way to get coloured output with git in cmd? If yes, how?

Platform: XP SP3.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: tested in Ubuntu. Should work in Windows but not tested.

From the "customizing git" [section](http://book.git-scm.com/5_customizing_git.html) of the [Git book](http://book.git-scm.com/index.html):

See all color.* options in the [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) docs

```
$ git config color.branch auto
$ git config color.diff auto
$ git config color.interactive auto
$ git config color.status auto
```

Or, you can set all of them on with the color.ui option:

```
$ git config color.ui true
```

Comment: Confirmed that this does work in msysGit's Bash shell on Windows. Also, you might want to make the setting apply globally (instead of just on the current project) with the command `git config --global color.ui true`